# Jupyter Notebooks gives me an empty page when I click on new terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have jupyter notebooks open and there is a button 'New' where you can select Python3 (ipykernel) Text File, Folder and Terminal

If I click on any of them they work and opens a new tab with whatever I selected, except new Terminal opens a new tab with a blank page http://localhost:8888/terminals/1

No errors in the terminal from which I launched it (my case VSCode terminal) and just a blank page.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that's because main terminal that you have is one you've opened Jupyter from, so it's supoused to look like that. But why you're not using built in extension of Jupyter inside VSCode? If you want to open Jupyter, without VSCode, then just open command prompt and execute "jupyter notebook" command. Tho I highly suggest using Jupyter Notebook extension inside VSCode

Comment: How is a blank page supposed to be? What difference does it make if I use VS Code to launch Jupyter Notebooks or if I use the normal terminal? Just trying to understand how a blank page can be "that's how it's supposed to look" Thanks

Comment: So to be sure I understooded correctly. You're opening Terminal in VSCode, than you run command "jupyter notebook", instance of jupyter is opened and you trying to open terminal instance from Jupyter terminal, that's right?

Comment: VS Code has a built in terminal so I simply inside the VS Code terminal enter jupyter-notebook and then a browser opens up and I see Jupyter notebook. On that page inside the browser is a button New and I select terminal and THAT opens a new tab and gives me an empty page.

Comment: What are your spec you running vs code and Jupyter? Is it Windows, Linux, WSL, Mac?
Place screenshot of this blank page please